# Is existence of site domain neccessary for generation API key?

Tags: api, google-maps, google-api, key

My site still haven't domain and I typed just "localhost" in field where site specified. And I've got answer "The Google Maps API server rejected your request. The provided API key is invalid.".
The same problem when I chose "service account" and "installed application".
Actually, I don't know what to chose, I have now just html files, and try to paste Google Map in one of them. But nothing works whatever application type I chose.
P. S. Sorry, I forgot to say that I use Embed API.

Comment: Try using the loopback ip instead, 127.0.0.1

Comment: Thanks for answer but key generated for 127.0.0.1 is invalid too.

Comment: can you please clarify: are you currently working on your local machine with an installed webserver?

Comment: Yes, local machine. Humm, not sure about webserver. I just open HTML file in browser.

Comment: Just in case I'm still clarify a couple of things: I'm doing prototype of site in Axure RP now, trying to add Google Map on one page, further I'm going to do ASP.NET app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't specify any referer, leave the field empty(or don't use a key until you move to a domain)

Comment: I tried to do it before asking: OAuth 2 redirect URL "http:///oauth2callback" is invalid.
    PostMessage Origin "http://" is invalid. http://snag.gy/rYgAl.jpg.

Comment: How can I built-in Google Map without key? If I simply delete it from query (like https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=Moscow), I'll get that "service requires an API key".

Comment: You forgot to mention that you use the embed-API(which requires the use of a key)...so you must define the key, but leave the referer empty

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'm a fool. Hmm, I don't understand how can I get key if referer will be empty. If I wrote nothing, I'll see again "Oath 2 ... is invalid" and "PostMessage ... is invalid".

Comment: you dont need OAuth there, all you need is the key for browser apps

Comment: Aha. Well, at least something is changed: "This API project is not authorized to use this API"

Comment: Oh, I wrote 127.0.0.1 to referer field, and now it works at last. Great thanks.